# What happened convert rgb to hsv

Tags: emgucv

Code :

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> inputImage = new Image<Bgr, Byte>("pic.jpg");
imageBox1.Image = inputImage;
Image<Hsv, byte> imageHsv = inputImage.Convert<Hsv, byte>();
imageBox2.Image = imageHsv;
```

Output:

[image: MY OUTPUT]